# Format Date in JS from .NET Service AJAX call

Tags: javascript, date

I have this problem.
I get a date from a .NET Service with an AJAX call.
The format of the date got is like this (I am in Italy)

```
Mon Dec 31 2012 08:25:21 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
```

How can I format this date in the format dd/MM/yyyy ?
I cannot work on the .NET service side, but only from the JS side.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the bits fairly easily to get a date object, then create a formatted string in whatever format you want. The following takes account of the timezone, which might be different from the client:

```
var s = 'Mon Dec 31 2012 08:25:21 GMT+0100';

function getDate(s) {

    // Split the string into bits
    var s = s.split(/[ :]/);

    // Conversion for month to month number (zero indexed)
    var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                  jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};

    // Calculate the offset in minutes
    var offsetMins = s[7].substring(4,6) * 60;
    offsetMins += s[7].substring(6,8) * 1;
    offsetMins *= s[7].substring(3,4) == '+'? 1 : -1;

    // Build a UTC date value, allowing for the offset in minutes,
    // and pass to the Date constructor
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC(s[3], months[s[1].toLowerCase()],
               s[2], s[4], (s[5] - offsetMins), s[6]));

    // return the date object
    return date;
}

function padN(n) {
  return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
}

var d = getDate(s);

alert(padN(d.getDate()) + '/' + padN(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer, retaining the time zone. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input format doesn't change:

```
var date = "Mon Dec 31 2012 08:25:21 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)"
var parts = date.split(' ');
var monthMap = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03", "Apr": "04", "May": "05", "Jun": "06", "Jul": "07", "Aug": "08", "Sep": "09", "Oct": "10", "Nov": "11", "Dec": "12"}
var formatted = parts[2]+"/"+monthMap[parts[1]]+"/"+parts[3]

// -> 31/12/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to parse the date, then recombine the bits into the required format.

```
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}


var dateString = "Mon Dec 31 2012 08:25:21 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)";

// I'm not sure what the Italian three letter month abbreviations are, so I've used English
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var m = dateString.match(/^\S{3} (\S{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4})/);

var formattedDate = pad(m[2]) + "/" + pad(months.indexOf(m[1])+1) + "/" + m[3];
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mhuxk/

Comment: This answer helped me very much to understand how I could work. Thank you very much.